# Binding dynamic data to kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a kendo dropdownlist with the model but I am getting undefined in each option.

Model:

```
public SelectList CountriesTemp { get; set; }
public int Country{get;set;}
```

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Registration()
{
RegistrationModel Model = new RegistrationModel();
Model.CountriesTemp = new SelectList(ObjService.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Country_Name");
return View(Model);
}
```

View Page

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
        //The name of the dropdownlist is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
  .DataTextField("Country_Name") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a text.
  .DataValueField("CountryID") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a value.
  .BindTo(Model.CountriesTemp )   //Pass the list of Products to the dropdownlist.
)
```

Can somebody please guide me where I am wrong because if I bind a simple dropdownlist of MVC , It works well. Just one line change as below in ViewPage and it's Working.

```
@Html.Dropdownlist("CountriesTemp")
```

Comment: Instead of `Model.CountriesTemp = new SelectList(ObjService.GetCountries(), "CountryID", "Country_Name")` try `Model.CountriesTemp = new ObjService.GetCountries();`. I don't think `Kendo.DropDownListFor()` uses a `SelectList`

Comment: And if it can, it would probably need to be `.DataTextField("Name")` and `.DataValueField("Value")` because they are the only (relevant) properties of `SelectList`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a conflict (so-to-speak going on here).  Try something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value") // These may be optional now
  .BindTo(Model.CountriesTemp))
```

Alternatively, you can not use a `SelectList` and do a property like `IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }` on your Model.  Then the binding would look something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Country)
  .DataTextField("Country_Name")
  .DataValueField("CountryID")
  .BindTo(Model.Countries))
```